# Tree boot or tree trunk

Tags: word-usage

I use an online app that defines tree trunk as US English and tree boot as British English. However, I can't find any reference anywhere else to tree boot. It the term still used?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Could the alternative to "tree trunk" have been "tree bole"? _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) defines _bole_ simply as "TRUNK 1a," where definition 1a of _trunk_ is "the main stem of a tree apart from limbs and roots—called also _bole_."

Answer (score 2):

"Trunk" in US English also refers to the compartment in the back of a car/vehicle where you store stuff. This compartment is called a "boot" in British English.

I'm pretty sure the app is, incorrectly, drawing from that sense of "trunk" and assuming that the word in the phrase "tree trunk" must also be replaceable with "boot". As far as I know, that's not true and "tree boot" has never been used in either form of English to mean the main stem of a tree.

Can I ask which app it is?

Comment: You are quite right, and well spotted. I am British, and have been for 70 years, and I have never heard of a *tree boot*, or a *tree bole*. We call it a *tree trunk*. But cars do not have *trunks* in Britain (only trees and elephants do). The luggage compartment of the car is *the boot*.

Comment: Bole is actually a quite legitimate word for tree trunk - it's in the dictionary.

Comment: @SimonB All I'm saying is that I have never heard it used. There are lots of words like that. But now I've learned it I shall probably hear it three times in the next week. Life's a bit like that isn't it.

Comment: The app is languagetool.org and a few days ago it stated that it's in need for someone to help with English. Nonetheless, it had been quite helpful in correcting other words and expressions. Your explanation had been quite helpful. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe "tree boot" has ever meant the same thing as "tree trunk". The app you are using is most likely confused because Americans call the cargo area of an automobile a "trunk", whereas the British call it the "boot".

E.G.:

American - "Get the luggage out of the trunk!"

British - "Get the luggage out of the boot!"

"Tree boot" returns no relevant results when searched. The term "tree trunk" comes from Latin *truncus*, which means *mutilated, cut off*.

Answer (score 1):

A google search for "boot" does not give you anything related to a tree, in British English or otherwise. As for the graph showing usage, the sudden increase in recent years can be attributed to it's usage in the context of computers.

A search for "trunk" on the other hand gives you a clear answer. It is the main woody stem of a tree.So my guess is that boot is not used in reference to a tree and you need to suggest improvements in the app. :)

Comment: The app, is https://www.languagetool.org/ and a few days ago it stated that it's in need for someone to help for English. Nonetheless, it had been quite helpful in correcting other words.